# Using a font sizing command in \addcontentsline does not work for ccfonts or cmbright

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

If you comment out \large in the code, it works.  The toc level doesn't matter. Any thoughts?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{ccfonts}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\begin{document}

           \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{%
                   \large
                    foo\hfill}}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\protect` before `\large`.

Answer (score 1):

The ToC is actually written to a file (`.toc`), and macros written to this file are usually expanded which is causing the problem here. You should `\protect` the font selection `\large` from expansion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{%
  \protect\large
  foo}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{{%
  %\protect\large
  bar}}%

\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

The above file's `.toc` looks like:

```
\contentsline {section}{{\large foo}}{1}
\contentsline {section}{{bar}}{1}
```

If you don't `\protect` it, then it looks like:

```
\contentsline {section}{{\edef \def 12.5{12.5}{\def 12.5{####2}}\edef \def 12.5{12.5}\relax \fontsize {12}{12.5}\selectfont foo}}{1}
\contentsline {section}{{bar}}{1}
```

and it's clear that the parameter usage `####2` has no context within `\contentsline`, resulting in an error.

<sub>You may have to delete the `.toc` (and `.aux`) if it contains faulty information before being able to compile successfully in subsequent runs.</sub>